# How to redirect page twice while get cookie

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, cookies, iframe

Firstly, I know this nearly impossible because someone can steal cookie if this possible. But because I am still doubtful around 1%, so I think I need to ask the community, so I can completely know if this still possible or completely impossible.

Let's say I have `mysite.com/promotion` which is permalink for `shop.org/aff.php?id=123`. **Id 123** is my affiliate ID. After visitor click that link, the visitor will redirected to shop.com/index.php (homepage). Then shop.com will command the visitor browser to save my affiliate cookie. **Note**: I have access for mysite.org but I don't have any access for shop.com.

The problem with this behaviour is that I only can promote the overall whole things about shop.org, but **I cannot promote his specific product link**. Because when I give the visitor a product link, I will not have any commission because the guest never access my affiliate url. But when I give him my affiliate url, he will need to find out where the product link is.

Now I will give some demo code to illustrate this.

shop.org/index.php

```
<?php session_start()?>
<h1>shop.com HOME PAGE</h1>
    <div>cookie affiliate: <span>EMPTY</span></div><br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"  ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['aff'])):?>
        Cookies.set('aff', '<?=$_SESSION['aff']?>');
        <?php endif;?>
        var aff = Cookies.get('aff');
        if(aff!==undefined){
            $('span').text(aff);
        }
        
    })
</script>
```

shop.org/aff.php?id=123

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['aff'] = $_GET['id'];
header('Location:https://shop.org/index.php');
```

shop.org/product.php

```
<?php session_start();?>
<p>shop.com PRODUCT PAGE</div>
<div>cookie affiliate: <span>EMPTY</span></div><br>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"  ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['aff'])):?>
        Cookies.set('aff', '<?=$_SESSION['aff']?>');
        <?php endif;?>
        var aff = Cookies.get('aff');
        if(aff!==undefined){
            $('span').text(aff);
        }
        
    })
</script>
```

Try 1: hidden iframe then redirect with js / html meta

mysite.org/promotion

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>INI REDIRECT</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://shop.org/product.php" />
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://shop.org/aff.php?id=123" width="0" height="0" tabindex="-1" title="empty" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <div>You will be redirect in 5 seconds</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Visitor will fail to get my affiliate cookie because he get warned : `A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://shop.org/ was set without the 'SameSite' attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with 'SameSite=None' and 'Secure'.`

Try 2: jQuery load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>INI REDIRECT</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=https://shop.org/product.php" />
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://shop.org/aff.php?id=123" width="0" height="0" tabindex="-1" title="empty" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <div>You will be redirect in 5 seconds</div>
    <div id="msgDiv"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"  ></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
             $('#msgDiv').load('https://shop.org/aff.php?id=123');
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

this will fail too, because CORS policy. Remember I don't have any access to shop.org, so I can't enable this.

Try 3: scraping the cookies then give visitor that cookies

I have not given code here, because I know this will fail too. The reason is we cannot give cross domain cookie to the browser.

My question is, is this completely impossible or still possible?

**Note**: if only 1 site, I just need to email them to fulfill my needs. But, shop.org is only 1 example of the most common affiliate system. So this question is only focusing without any change at server. Yes, impossible, but I just have a little doubt here.

Comment: You need shop.org support. Whatever you choose. Any redirection, sneaky tricks etc are not best way, even if they work today, tomorrow can fail. Your id in the url is not enough for them?

Comment: An affiliate link shouldn't require a cookie, it should be a URL parameter that the server the client is being redirected to recognizes and calculates.

Comment: thanks @blackblue but shop.org is only an example.

Comment: @SJacks i use url in the demo, then save data using cookie for future purpose. As long as i know, common affiliate system is like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's nearly impossible, because the CORS-Policy is exactly to block this cases.
You can do something like this only if the other site allows this with a specific HTTP-Header.

You can try `<img src="https://shop.org/aff.php?id=123" style="height: 0; width: 0;">`, but i think the result would be the same to the iframe.

**Other method:**

Maybe the shop-page offers this method, for example with a GET-Attribute:

*shop.com/aff.php?id=123&url=/product/myproduct/*

or

*shop.com/product/myproduct/?aff=123*